# dm snapshot - how does it work?

Tags: linux, lvm, device-mapper

Fedora uses dm-snapshot for making the root filesystem read-write.  At least for me, when running a livecd (even without touching it), it will become unusable relatively quickly meaning it has exhausted the default 512MB tmpfs overlay.  I find this hard to believe that if I just boot up to it, do nothing, and in a few days it will consume 512MB.  I have other systems using aufs to do the same thing and they've been stable for months and longer.

I suspect that dm-snapshot essentially requires the size of tmpfs to match the size of the source filesystem, not the size of what changes.  If that is the case, dm-snapshot seems like a horrible option for making root read-write.

Please clarify how dm-snapshot works.  According to what I've read, it only consumes the size of the changes.

Comment: Hmm, it appears other filesystems such as /tmp (tmpfs), /dev/shm are writing to the overlay instead of the tmpfs volume.  What would be causing this?